# Can I tell the compiler to prefer baseTypes for extensions (with same signature)

Tags: c#, string, .net-6.0

My issue: with .NET 6, the `.StartsWith` / `.IndexOf` / etc. methods in `System.Runtime` lib perform a lot worse than in previous versions of the framework.

The 'fast' implementations are now in the `System.MemoryExtensions` namespace, using `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

---

Edit i just found my real issue.
When not using StringComparison, the default is CurrentCulture. And Current Culture performs ~7 times worse than in framework (de-DE) And initially i compared Runtime .StartsWith (with CurrentCulture) with memoryextensions Ordinal

UsedCode (using Benchmark.net):

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class BenchForFlydog57
{
    string somestring = "SomeString";
    [Benchmark]
    public bool SystemRuntimeStartsWith() => somestring.StartsWith("ABEC");
    [Benchmark]
    public bool MemoryExtensionStartsWith() => MemoryExtensions.StartsWith(somestring.AsSpan(), "ABEC".AsSpan(), StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Results:
[image]

Using StringCompareOrdinal, leads to following result:

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class BenchForFlydog57
{
    string somestring = "SomeString";
    [Benchmark]
    public bool SystemRuntimeStartsWith() => somestring.StartsWith("ABEC", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    [Benchmark]
    public bool MemoryExtensionStartsWith() => MemoryExtensions.StartsWith(somestring.AsSpan(), "ABEC".AsSpan(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

[image]

This means my issue is solved and even performs better if we just specify the StringComparison to Ordinal.

Comment: Look up the alternate use of a `using` declaration. You can say `using fast = System.MemoryExtensions` and then call something like `fast.SomeFunction`

Comment: @Flydog57 hmmm, dont think this really helps. In this case i have to go over every use anyway. 
My current attempt is adding .AsSpan() to every string used with startswith etc.. 
I am searching for a solution where I dont have to alter every single use

Comment: I'm surprised by your statement that certain `string` functions in .NET 6 _"perform a lot worse than in Framework."_ Have you benchmark this? Do you have a source for this statement?

Comment: @Flydog57 oh I just found my issue.... when not using a specific stringcomparison it uses currentculture. And currentcultre compare performans 8 times worse than in framework.  So using StringComparison.Ordinal makes it 200x faster than without StringComparison (i use benchmark.net) i will add it to my question in some minutes

Comment: @Flydog57 added my measurments. Still surprised that .net6 performs worse in some cases than framework; but as usual the real issue is the developer in front of the screen. Just use StringComparison.Ordinal as you should do.

Comment: Have you tried using outside of the namespace and the prefared inside of the namespace?

Comment: Was not able to repro. Your first benchmark shows `.NET 6` being faster while for .NET 4.8 the perfromance is roughly the same. What culture is you `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Also you can try adding `<ItemGroup> <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" /> </ItemGroup>` to your csproj, see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)

Comment: @GuruStron de-DE ; yea i realized that i compared CurrentCulture (System.Runtime) with Ordinal (MemoryExtensions). Still the difference seems irrationally large.